# Treat Android Phone as remote controller to other Android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I am working on the Final Year Project whcih require to use one android phone to control other phone via blue-tooth or wi-fi. I am very new for this area so I have no idea where should I start it.

The basic require is the controller can swap the screen and tap the object.  Is there any site or example I can refer to ?

Here is the example app I find on Internet
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/tablet-remote-control-one-android-device-with-another-via-bluetooth/

So I am wonder if I can use GesturesBuilder to write this app? As one phone be the server and one as client. I making action on server and the client will receive the signal to perform the same action.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible, except perhaps if the receiving phone is rooted.

Comment: @Alexander I only ask 5 questions on Stack OverFlow, this is one of it, and only 1 question ever been sovle, most of it rather no one answear or the answer is nothing realte to my question.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I have seen some application on market that allow to do this without root the device so I come to ask this question. Here is one of the app I have find http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/tablet-remote-control-one-android-device-with-another-via-bluetooth/

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I will take steps to ensure that the security issue that you have illustrated is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use socket programming to do this. See here: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

Comment: thank you, I will like to try the code once I get all the equipment I need. I want to ask can I use GesturesBuilder to write this app? As one phone be the server and one as client. I making action on server and the client will receive the signal to perform the same action.

Comment: You can use whatever you want to write your application. You have my permission. Perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection

Answer (score 0):

That app is bluetooth remote control andoid app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shakej.blectrl.toll